# CGBitmapContextCreateImage error

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, avfoundation

I am getting error like this In my console:

: CGBitmapContextCreate: invalid data bytes/row: should be at least 1920 for 8 integer bits/component, 3 components, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst.
: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0

I use below code:

```
- (UIImage *) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer 
{
    // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
    // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0); 

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer); 

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer); 
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer); 
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer); 

    // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 

    // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, 
                                                 bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst); 
    // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context); 
    // Unlock the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    // Free up the context and color space
    CGContextRelease(context); 
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Create an image object from the Quartz image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];

    // Release the Quartz image
    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

    return (image);
}
```

Comment: If you NSLog `bytesPerRow`, `width` and `height`, what are the results?

Comment: no image display in imageView

Comment: I mean, if you add `NSLog(@"%zi, %zi, %zi",width,height,bytesPerRow);` before `CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();`, what is output on the console?

Comment: it give this 3 value --480, --360, --724

Comment: Then there's something very wrong with `sampleBuffer`. A valid BGRA `CMSampleBufferRef` will have a number of bytes per row that is at *least* four times the width of the image represented. Your problem is almost certainly not with this code (which is just copy-pasted from Apple anyway), but with the code that is calling it, by the look of things.

Comment: I pass sampleBuffer  same as this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1702/_index.html

Comment: also when i print the image NSLog(@"photo :%@",image); it give photo : <UIImage: 0x555900>

Comment: Logging the UIImage isn't relevant. The problem is clearly that you are not passing a valid `CMSampleBufferRef`, so you need to debug the code that is responsible for creating it, not the code that appears to be behaving correctly considering it is being fed garbage data. Technical Q&A QA1702 is not a complete application, so you *must* have changed and added thinks to make it run. Something further back in the code must be wrong...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

this is what fixed my problem:
as "Wildaker" suggested, it is "the code that's calling it", more or less.

in the Apple Example the output format is set.
perhaps you skipped this part to simplify ?!

`output.videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey: (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];`

Comment: This is exactly what I did not do ^^ thank you for the lesson!

Comment: for Swift 3: output.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as AnyHashable : kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]

Answer (score 0):

`void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);`should be changed to : `uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t*)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);`

Comment: you can use a code block to show you code in better way. and can add bit more description. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your advice,and i will note that these