# Convert CMSampleBufferRef to UIImage with YUV color space?

Tags: ios, uiimage, avcapturesession, yuv, bgr

I'm working with `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and want to convert `CMSampleBufferRef` to `UIImage`. Many answers are the same, like this [UIImage created from CMSampleBufferRef not displayed in UIImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305862/uiimage-created-from-cmsamplebufferref-not-displayed-in-uiimageview) and [AVCaptureSession with multiple previews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543075/avcapturesession-with-multiple-previews)

It works fine if I set the VideoDataOutput color space to BGRA (credited to this answer [CGBitmapContextCreateImage error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243511/cgbitmapcontextcreateimage-error))

```
NSString* key = (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey;
NSNumber* value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA];
NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value forKey:key];
[dataOutput setVideoSettings:videoSettings];
```

Without the above videoSettings, I will receive the following errors

```
CGBitmapContextCreate: invalid data bytes/row: should be at least 2560 for 8 integer bits/component, 3 components, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst.
<Error>: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0
```

Working with BGRA is not a good choice, since there is conversion overhead from YUV (default AVCaptureSession color space) to BGRA, as stated by Brad and Codo in [How to get the Y component from CMSampleBuffer resulted from the AVCaptureSession?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085474/how-to-get-the-y-component-from-cmsamplebuffer-resulted-from-the-avcapturesessio)

So is there a way to convert `CMSampleBufferRef` to `UIImage` and working with YUV color space ?

Comment: @AdarshVC why don't you vote the question to make it more noticable ?

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305862/uiimage-created-from-cmsamplebufferref-not-displayed-in-uiimageview

Comment: @entropy I voted already. long before :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After doing a lots of research and read apple documentations and wikipedis. I figured out the answer and it is works perfectly for me. So for the future readers Im sharing the code to convert `CMSampleBufferRef` to `UIImage` when video pixel type is set as `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange`

```
// Create a UIImage from sample buffer data
// Works only if pixel format is kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange
-(UIImage *) imageFromSamplePlanerPixelBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer{

    @autoreleasepool {
        // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
        CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

        // Get the number of bytes per row for the plane pixel buffer
        void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);

        // Get the number of bytes per row for the plane pixel buffer
        size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer,0);
        // Get the pixel buffer width and height
        size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
        size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

        // Create a device-dependent gray color space
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

        // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8,
                                                     bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);
        // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
        CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
        // Unlock the pixel buffer
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

        // Free up the context and color space
        CGContextRelease(context);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

        // Create an image object from the Quartz image
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];

        // Release the Quartz image
        CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

        return (image);
    }
}
```

Comment: what about other colors?

Comment: @JULIIncognito chnage the color space to rgb

Comment: @Bluewings by changing the colorSpace to  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); it doesn't work... Is it working color image for you ? Thank

Comment: @Bluewings by changing the colorSpace to CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), the result is still grayscale image. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Linjie @lilouch what is your `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` videoSettings dictionary values?

Comment: @Bluewings I figured out the problem. By using    ```CGBitmapContextCreateImage``` it only extracts the Y channel so the result is always grayscale. I have to implement a function to manually convert YUV to RGB values following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31553521/2298638

Comment: Best example on stack overflow.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

// it works for me.

```
var image: CGImage?
VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, options: nil, imageOut: &image)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: image!)
}
```